# VS 2012 express debugging another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, debugging, visual-studio-2012, multi-tenant

I'm using VS 2012 express to build a "multi-tenanted" website with MVC4. The website itself is all going swimmingly.

In order to ensure separation of concerns, I have a plugin type of architecture, whereby I have other projects in my solution, one for each "tenant" so to speak. This means I can have a core website and just plug in a tenant plugin when required.

This appears to work fine. How it works is that on a build, various files get xcopied into the host site. It's a slight nuisance that a change to a .cshtml for example, I have to build to get the latest, but no matter.

I did also have problems trying to connect the database for the host with the database for the tenant through linq (so that I could have user specific data from the tenant, based on the logged in user on the host), but that is working now.

However, I am now hitting a bit of a road block and it is drastically slowing me down.

Because the files are xcopied, they don't appear to come under the debugger, so putting in a breakpoint on a tenant controller has absolutely no effect.

Does anyone know (or have any ideas) on how to debug the tenant DLL? All ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it again... been puzzling over the problem for quite a while and then worked out how to do it.

In the "tenant" project properties, click "Web". CHECK "Override application root URL" and use the same URL as the host website.

Basically, the host is using IIS Express, on http://localhost:51402 the "tenant", even though it is not the main project was using http://localhost:49931 so was not getting connected as the tenant project was not technically being run.

Making it use the same URL by overriding application root URL allowed it to connect.

**EDIT**

Now, I am not so sure that the above actually solved the problem, partially solved it or was just timing that made it look like it solved it.

Reason being, I had it happen again where it didn't debug. However, hovering over the breakpoint, it said the source was different to what is currently running. This confused me a little.

It seems that when a build happens by clicking the green go button, the post build events that are in the properties are not executed. In the post build, I have the xcopy to copy the files over to the host app.

So, that means I have to build by hand, then run the green button (and build again).